# Positining elements according to browser size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a question about positining elements on the screen. When I start my program, it calculates the browser's width and half of the height. I do it only at the beginning. So my horizontal scroller stands at the center, but when I change the browser size during program run, of course it doesn't stand at center. How can I do that?

My calculation of width and height:

```
  function GetWidth()
{
      var x = 0;
      if (self.innerHeight)
      {
              x = self.innerWidth;
      }
      else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight)
      {
              x = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
      }
      else if (document.body)
      {
              x = document.body.clientWidth;
      }
      return x;
}
function GetHeight()
{
      var y = 0;
      if (self.innerHeight)
      {
              y = self.innerHeight;
      }
      else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight)
      {
              y = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
      }
      else if (document.body)
      {
              y = document.body.clientHeight;
      }
      return y;
}
```

Comment: Have you google'd for [media queries](https://www.google.co.in/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=media+queries)

Answer (score 1):

Hopefuly this will help you: [Media Queries CSS](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

Have a read about these, its what i use to display and control my content between mobiles,tablets and desktops.

Its very hand and easy to use.

Comment: +1 if possiblem, media-queries are much more elegant than a javascript-based solution.

Answer (score 1):

use the [onresize-event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onresize) to readjust your gui.

```
function resize() {
  // do something here
}

window.onresize = resize;
```

Comment: Whats the preformance and elegance difference between this and media quiers?

Comment: I used this but it didn't effected.

Comment: @Liam McCann: i agree with you that media queries should be used if possible, but we don't have information about what exactly should be achived and how Ahmet Tanakols site works. maybe there are things that have to be dynamically created or scaled by javascript on every +-10 pixels of resizing - and you don't want to have 180 media queries for browsers sizes between 200 and 2000

Comment: Yes, sorry wasn't trying to say you were wrong, was just curious myself on which way was better or how they were different as it may affect my future work.